# 30 charactres maximum in a line in linux using tr/sed

Tags: linux

I have a text file (a story) that I need to organize it in a way that I have 30 chars at most in each line. how do I do it using sed/tr commands?
thanks!

- I have to do the task using only sed/tr commands

Comment: I'd rather use `fmt` than `sed` or `tr`.

Comment: unfortunately I have to use sed or tr for the task

Comment: Do you care about word-boundaries?

Comment: so I can assume that no word is larger than 30 characters and I don't wanna cut a word in the middle so it's fine if the line is a little smaller than 30 characters.

Comment: Use `fmt(1)` from GNU coreutils. It should already be installed on your system. Hint: `fmt -w 30 FILE`.

Comment: @Ben Menahem - Define _word_.